# Swift 3 - Delay Repeating Animation

Tags: swift, swift3, uiviewanimation

Currently, this animation repeats itself every 3ish seconds.  I would like to have a wait time of 10 seconds in between repeating this animation.   How can I accomplish this?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 7.5, delay: 20,
                   options: .repeat,
                   animations: {
        self.imageAnimate.center.x += self.view.bounds.width * 2
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Timer`:

```
// note that I used 17.5 here because the animation itself takes 7.5 seconds
// so that will be 7.5 seconds of animating, 10 seconds of doing nothing
// and start animating again
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 17.5, repeats: true) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 7.5, animations: {
        self.imageAnimate.center.x += self.view.bounds.width * 2
    })
}
```